# Как получить координаты курсора на UWP C#?

Tags: c#, windows, курсор

Как получить координаты курсора на Universal Windows C#?

Comment: В event handler'е это делается без проблем. Расскажите, какую задачу вы решаете.

Comment: @закрывающие: да ладно вам, вопрос по идее неплохой (особенно после подчистки).

Comment: @VladD есть картинка, разделённая на блоки линиями. При нажатии на определённый блок должна выдаваться опрелелённая информация. По-сути, можно сравнить с кнопками, просто тут блоки нужно ограничить координатами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Окей, у вас есть клик, это меняет дело.

Подпишитесь на клик по нужному контролу, и в event handler'е делайте так:

```
void OnPointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PointerDevice.PointerDeviceType != PointerDeviceType.Mouse)
    {
        // это была не мышь, отреагируйте как-то
    }

    // 
    PointerPoint pp = e.GetCurrentPoint(relativeTo: this);
    Point point = pp.Position;
    // обрабатывайте
}
```

Comment: Разобрался, но сейчас проблема в другом. Как я понял, когда я ставлю условие `(((point.X >=412)&&(point.X <= 645))&&((point.Y >= 68)&&(point.Y <= 174)))` считаются координаты указателя относительно окна. Можно ли как нибудь считать координаты относительно картинки?

Comment: @DavidArutiunian: `relativeTo: this`. Подставьте вместо `this` картинку.